# why is strtotime("now -1hours") a different format (am/pm) than strtotime("now +1hours") (24h)?

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format, strtotime

I'm doing an INSERT into my db with these PHP variables:

```
$startdate1=strtotime("now -1hours");
$enddate1=strtotime("now +1hours");
$startdate= date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $startdate1);
$enddate= date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $enddate1);
```

Now, `$startdate` formats in 24h format. For example, right now it's 13:58 where I live and the db entry correctly is `2016-04-11 12:58:37`

But `$enddate` seems to format in AM/PM! Accordingly, right now it's 13:58 and the db entry is `2016-04-11 02:58:37`.

Does someone know why they get formatted differently? I need both in 24h format, so `$enddate` should be `2016-04-11 14:58:37` instead of `2016-04-11 02:58:37`.

Comment: It isn't a different format; they both 12-hr clock: date format masks..... lower-case `h` = 12hr clock, upper-case `H` = 24hr clock

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: @MarkBaker omg thank you.. That was it. Sorry for this goddamn newbie question! I really didn't recognize them both  being 12-hr clock format..